# Scala Slick update

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I'm new to scala and slick. I have to write an update statement to update a value in properties table.

```
def updateValue(key: String, value: String) = Try(Tables.Properties.filter(_.key === key).map(j => j.value).update(Option(value)) ) match {
   case success => println("Record sucessfully updated")
   case failure => println("An error occurred")
}
```

The above method is executing without any error but when I check in the table, it is not updating any value in the table. Is there anything else I have to add here?

Comment: it seems that you already found the problem. you were missing the `db.run`. Hoping that you can find it useful have a look at this tutorial I wrote a while ago: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/ with the code example at https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps/tree/step3

Comment: Thanks. I will go though it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem. I should use db.run() to update.

```
def updateValue2(key: String, value: String) = {
  val action = Tables.Properties.filter(_.key === key).map(j => j.value).update(Option(value))
  db.run(action)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `Success(x)` and `Failure(x)`, not `success`/`failure`.

What you have when you use a lowercase name after the `case` is a variable populated with the result, which means that `case success` will always execute (i.e. whatever happens the variable `success` will be populated) and `case failure` will never execute.

The variable in the parentheses is populated with the successful result (i.e. `Success(a)`, `a` holds the result) or the exception thrown (i.e. `Failure(b)`, `b` holds the exception).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation